# How can I burn CD/DVD from delphi2007 win32

Tags: delphi, cddvd

Is there any good lib to enable me to burn CD/DVD from Delphi 2007 win32 ?
Thanks

Comment: Another solution in newer Windows versions (since XP SP2): http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2009/07/18/im-burning-baby

Answer (score 8):

I know of a couple:

- [Bayden's Delphi CD Burning Library](http://www.bayden.com/delphi/cdburner.htm)
- [Dance Mammal's](http://www.dancemammal.com/) Free Delphi CD Burning Library
- Zyl Burner for Delphi (Needs Nero to be installed).

Answer (score 4):

<strike>We are using [Magic CD/DVD Burner VCL](http://www.binarymagics.com/site/magic_cddvd_burner_vcl.html) and are quite happy with it.</strike>

Binary Magic is also making a bunch of related products (Bluray burning, .NET version, audio burning ...) so be sure to check out their [products](http://www.binarymagics.com/site/products.html) page.

EDIT: My fellow codeveloper informed me that we have problems with Magic CD/DVD Burner and newer DVD writers and that it's impossible to get any feedback from Binary Magic's support :( So you maybe should stay away from them.

EDIT2: We are now just calling [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) command line interface. It's simple, works and is regularly updated.