# Write to a CD from Delphi

Tags: delphi, cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I burn CD/DVD from delphi2007 win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383938/how-can-i-burn-cd-dvd-from-delphi2007-win32)

I am looking for a free and open source component or source code to write to a CD from Delphi 2007. Do you know any?

Comment: The image mastering api is the win32 native way; try googling for delphi +imapi

Comment: Do you need this tightly integrated in a Delphi app? The reason I ask is that IMAPI may be easier to drive from Python or vbscript than Delphi.

Comment: [JEDI Windows API blog](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2009/07/18/im-burning-baby/) with some interesting links and comments.

Comment: @TOndrej put that as an answer and you will surely accrue significant upvotes

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes I have finished writing a project with Delphi 2007 and now I need to Write some data to a CD.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick search on Google reveals this [JEDI Windows API blog post](http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2009/07/18/im-burning-baby/) with some interesting links and comments. Perhaps it's an option to start with.

Comment: It seems TDiscMaster from the above blog is a good class to work with writer, but the demo does not work for me!
**A generic error occurred.** error raises when trying to burn with the original demo! Has anyone worked with it?

Comment: @mtoloo My experience with IMAPI is that it is very brittle and often hardware dependent. My IMAPI scripts work on only around 50% of the machines in the office. The problem may not be with the JEDI component and may in fact occur with anything that uses IMAPI.